# Why do we subtract the $cdf_{min}$ in this step of histogram equalisation?

Tags: histogram, image-processing

In my question I am referring to histogram equalisation as it is described in the wikipedia article in this example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_equalization#Small_image).

Given an grey image $I$ of size $M \times N$, in histogram equalisation one computes a cumulative distribution function $(cdf)$ for each grey value $v$ and counts how many different grey values were used in total $(L)$.

After that one can give each pixel of the image a new value by putting together all information above:

$$h(v) =
 round
 \left(
   \frac {cdf(v) - cdf_{min}} {(M \times N) - cdf_{min}}
   \times (L - 1)
 \right)
$$

This fomular however includes a $-cdf_{min}$ in the denominator and I am not really sure for the reason.

But I can look at two different scenarios:

Given that $cdf_{min}$ is small, I would expect that to be the normal case then $cdf_{min}$ becomes negligible to $M \times N$. However I notice: The nominator starts out small and becomes bigger for bigger $v$ values.

The denominator is constant and expected to be big.

In the second case, I assume that $cdf_{min}$ is big, making all other $cdf(v)$ values big and the denominator small. Furthermore the nominator starts small and stays small.

Therefore these two cases behave differently and I don't really see why the $cdf_{min}$ is included in the denominator at all.